# Preflight of cross domain Ajax with custom header (using jquery) always getting cancelled

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, cors

I am trying to make a cross domain POST with custom headers, but the preflight always getting cancelled (That's the word in Chrome's "Inspect Element" panel >> "Network" label), and I cannot tell whether it was cancelled by the browser or by jQuery. Code is:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    'type'        : 'POST',
    'crossDomain' : true,
    'url'         : 'https://host.domain/some_path',
    'data'        : {'some_key': 'some_value'},
    'headers'     : {
        'Authorization'        : 'CUSTOM-METHOD credential_id:credential_secret',
        'X-Some-Custom-Header' : '2013-05-02'
    }
})
.done(function(blah){blah})
.fail(function(blah){blah});
```

- If I remove the headers object, or set it to {}, then the request can be made successfully.
- If I remove the Authorization header, the preflight will still be cancelled.

I don't think it's server-side issue, because there is nothing about the OPTIONS request method in server's log. I think the preflight request was never been made.

So, any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it showing in the console tab?

Comment: @Obaid There is nothing in the console tab. Although, if I use `console.log(request)`, I can see the readyState of the request is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: it's a problem with the credential used in HTTPS, nothing to do with the codes.

I generated the server credential myself, need to tell the browser to trust the credential.